# Show that $n$ divides $2^{n!} -1$ for all odd $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Show that $n$ | $2^{n!}-1$ for all odd $n$.

I tried to show this by using Fermat's theorem but was unable to reach anything close. Since $n!$ is even then $2^{n!}$ is a square and so $2^{n!}$$-1$ is a difference of squares. Now we can assume that ${n!}$ = $2k$ and factorize it as ($2^k$$-1$)($2^k$$+1$). So we want to show that $n$ divides any one of these 2 factors. How exactly can we reach that?

Comment: Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem

Comment: Can you show it for $n$ prime first?

Comment: If $n$ odd is a product of different prime numbers it's easy to prove with Fermat's little theorem  because if $p$ is such a prime then $p-1$ divides $n!$. But if $n$ is divisible by a power of a prime number, greater than $1$, this proof fails.

Comment: If $\varphi(n)$ divides $n!$ the problem is solved because Euler's theorem can be used.